# Fill current row and column value with previous row column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have set of readings and I need current and previous value to measure some parameters. How do I populate easily in pandas such that current row, column value takes from previous row, column value. If prev row,col doesn't exit, then I want to fill with -1 or `na` or anything.

```
 events  = np.array([[  3.,   -1., 441., 780.,  30., 262.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  -1.],
       [  4.,   3., 437., 770.,  30., 274.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  -1.],
       [  5.,   4, 431., 754.,  31., 286.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  -1.]]) 

df=pd.DataFrame(data=events, columns=["curr", "expected_prev", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7","prev"])
```

For example, I want to fill values in panda dataframe as below. The below `expected_prev` is hardcoded, how do I generate or fill the `prev` column in pandas.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with `shift`

```
df['exp_pre'] = df['curr'].shift().fillna(-1)
```

Comment: I tried this, `df.loc[:, 'prev'] = df.loc[1:, 'curr']`. Liking your solution!

Comment: `df.curr.shift(fill_value=-1)`